# If function 1 always has a bigger gradient than function 2, is the value of function 1 always greater?

Tags: functions

Suppose we have two functions $$ f(x),g(x):R \to R   $$
such that    $$f^{\prime}(x) > g^{\prime}(x) \  \forall x\in [a,b]\ $$ and $$f(a)=g(a) $$
Is it fair to say that $$f(x) > g(x) \forall x \in[a,b] $$ ? I know its a trivial question but i used it to prove something and want to make sure.

Comment: I think it’s correct; consider using Rolle’s theorem on $f-g$ to obtain a contradiction

Comment: oh yeah thats true thanks @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we think of the special case where $x=a$ it is false. Because $f(a) = g(a)$.

If we care about $(a,b]$ then it is correct. Here's a proof:

Let $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$. Obviously $h'(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$ so $h$ is a strictly increasing function in $[a,b]$.

But $h(a) = f(a) - g(a) = 0$.

So for every $x \in [a,b]$ it must hold $x>a \Rightarrow h(x) > h(a) \Rightarrow f(x) - g(x) > 0 \Rightarrow f(x) > g(x)$

Comment: right, its supposed be an open interval anyways. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $f(x) >g(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b]$.